# Stable and elegant use of expression for `qr`

Tags: regex, perl

In some code I create a constant regular expression where the regular expression contains a Perl expression ("code"), and I wonder whether there is a stable (i.e.: non-experimental) and more elegant solution than this (using Perl 5.18.2):

```perl
use constant    RE_SAMPLE => (
    map { qr/$_/ }
    ('^(' .
     join('|',
          qw(many cool strings and stuff like that)) .
     ')(?::(.+))?$')
)[0];
```

I mean the ugly part is making a list from the expression, just to map it, and then just take the only element from the list as a result.

Comment: What is it that you mean is the experimental part of this? `use constant`? You could just use a regular variable, or a sub. I think it is unclear what your question is. Is this a question for a library recommendation?

Comment: In Perl 5.18.0 and later, the qr operator supports the `/x` modifier, which allows you to include comments and whitespace in your regular expression pattern. This can be used to make your regular expression more readable without the need for additional constructs like `map`.

Comment: @ImGroot  They cannot have `join` under the `qr` (or any code)

Comment: I don't see anything experimental in there. As for elegance, code review questions belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Bork (and others): I'm *not* using experimental features; instead I mentioned it to avoid answers using `${code}` which is documented as *experimental*.

Comment: `${code}` is not experimental, nor documented as such.

Comment: If your goal is to match many strings efficiently, consider using [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble)

Comment: @U.Windl If you meant you don't want experimental answers, you should have wrote that. In general, your question is very confusing and vague. You should consider clarifying what it is you are asking.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `qr()`? I would say in most cases you can skip using qr, if you use the string inside a regex operator. I.e. it might be premature optimization.

Comment: @Bork The regex is used multiple times at different places, and I wanted to avoid the compilation overhead.

Comment: @U.Windl You mean like this: `$foo =~ RE_SAMPLE`? I noticed that the constants do not interpolate in regexes, so the only way to use them would be to do that, or use string concatenation (which would require a new compilation). Perl is usually very optimized when it comes to regex compilation, and it would not surprise me if your optimization is premature. You could do a benchmark to find out.

Comment: @Brok constants *do* interpolate in regex, but that's ugly like `qr/^(?:${\RE_INSTANCE})|(?:${\RE_ANY})$/`.  A `join('|', map { '(?:' . $_ . ')' } RE_INSTANCE, RE_ANY)`would be easier to read, I guess. Thus the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be too much for one statement that is also meant to be clean and elegant.<sup>†</sup>

Why not break it up

```
use constant PATT => do { 
    my $alt = join '|', qw(many cool strings);
    qr/^ ($alt) (?: :(.+) )? $/x;
};
```

I find this just fine looking?

---

I prefer [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast), which creates a lexical.  For one, it's easier to use in regex patterns.

```
use Const::Fast;

const my $p => do { 
    my $alt = join '|', qw(many cool strings);
    qr/^ ($alt) (?: :(.+) )? $/x;
};
```

Now this `$p` can be used (interpolated) as any old lexical.

---

<sup>†</sup> Mostly out of curiosity, here are some ways to do it in one statement

- Using an [Extended pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns) of [embedded code](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(??%7B-code-%7D))

  ```
  my $re = qr/^ ( (??{ join '|', qw(a b) }) ) (?: :(.+) )? $/x;
  ```

  The `(?? { ... })` version of this complex feature uses the return value of the code inside `{}` as a subpattern in the regex. Study the docs for warnings and limitations.
- With an anonymous sub, defined and ran in one statement, so that one can pass into it stuff that can't be directly under `qr` (like code) and do the rest in the sub body

  ```
  my $re = sub { qr/^($_[0]) (? :(.+) )? $/x }->( join '|', qw(a b) );
  ```

  I do *not* recommend this in production code as I see no benefit over a clear multi-statement piece of code while it is pretty much opposite of clear.  But I do find it interesting

These can be made read-only, using `constant` or `Const::Fast` (or yet other libs).

In my understanding the question asked specifically for ways *other than* these.

Comment: Yes, I had something like that in my mind, too: First I thought I could assign the result of a closure being called with the regex as argument, but then I realized that a block is mostly equivalent. That avoids the list.

Comment: @U.Windl Perhaps you mean an anonymous sub, defined and ran in one statement, what separates things -- can pass into it stuff that can't be under `qr` (like code) and do the rest in the sub body: `$re = sub { qr/($_[0]) \s+ (.+)/x }->( join "|", qw(a b c) );`.  Now that's one statement ... which is a li'l complex.  There are other ways to split "duties" -- what's passed in, what's in the body ... but it's kinda opposite of readable.

Comment: @U.Windl Runable: `perl -wE'$in = shift // "b ho"; $re = sub { qr/($_[0]) \s+ (.+)/x }->( join "|", qw(a b c) ); $in =~ $re; say for $1,$2'`. Prints `b ho`. Can pass input string instead, `perl -wE'...' "input"`

Answer (score 2):

```perl
use constant RE_SAMPLE => qr/
   ^
   ( many
   | cool
   | strings
   | and
   | stuff
   | like
   | that
   )
   (?: : (.+) )?
   $
/x;
```

Comment: That `qw` was just an example. I reality those are other constants. Finally: Of course I can write it down like that, but then I wouldn't have asked...

Comment: I answered the question asked, which is about (many cool) strings. If you meant to ask something else, ask that, and ask it on the right site. https://codereview.stackexchange.com